# Apply jQuery event to one class at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple images with the same class and I want to hide those images once file is uploaded to corresponding filed.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
  $(".hide").hide();
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="hide" src="img1.png">
<label>Choose Image1</label>: <input type="file">

<img class="hide" src="img2.png">
<label>Choose Image2</label>: <input type="file">
```

This code hides all images if I upload a file.

I want to hide only the `img1` if I uploaded file `Image1` and so on.

Comment: `$(this).previous(".hide").hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have each file row in separate containers I suggest using the jQuery [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector or a combination of the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Sibling Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hide').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img class="hide" src="img1.png">
  <label>Choose Image1</label>: <input type="file">
</div>

<div>
  <img class="hide" src="img2.png">
  <label>Choose Image2</label>: <input type="file">
</div>
```

Closest + Find Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.hide').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <img class="hide" src="img1.png">
  <div>
  <label>Choose Image1</label>: <input type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <img class="hide" src="img2.png">
  <div>
  <label>Choose Image2</label>: <input type="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting class which hides all. You should look at [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) which just selects previous element with given class name.

```
  $(this).prev(".hide").hide();
```

---

```
$(document).rady(function() {
 $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        $(this).prev(".hide").hide();

   });
});
```

Comment: `prev` function `Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.`

Comment: My <img class="hide"> is in another <div> and file input field in another div.

Comment: @universal in that case , can you try   `$(this).parent("div").prev("div").find(".hide").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the previous elements with the class `hide` and take thee first one from that. [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
  $(this).prevAll(".hide").first().hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="hide" src="img1.png">
<label>Choose Image1</label>: <input type="file">
<br>
<img class="hide" src="img2.png">
<label>Choose Image2</label>: <input type="file">
<br>
<img class="hide" src="img3.png">
<label>Choose Image3</label>: <input type="file">
<br>
<img class="hide" src="img4.png">
<label>Choose Image4</label>: <input type="file">
```

Comment: My ``<img class="hide">`` is in another <div> and file input field in another div.